# Update column with values from another table if ID exists in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables,

Table1:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Value |
+----+-------+
| 1  |   A   |
| 2  |   B   |
| 3  |   C   |
| 4  |   D   |
+----+-------+
```

Table2:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Value |
+----+-------+
| 3  |   E   |
| 4  |   F   |
+----+-------+
```

Table1 after update

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Value |
+----+-------+
| 1  |   A   |
| 2  |   B   |
| 3  |   E   |
| 4  |   F   |
+----+-------+
```

I want to update all 'Value' columns in table 1 where there is a matching ID in table 2, and leave the rest of the values who do not have a matching ID in table 2 to be left alone, as in the example above.

Essentially the following:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Value = (SELECT Value FROM Table2 
             WHERE Table1.[ID] = Table2.[ID])
```

Except this makes all values in Table1 NULL that are not present in Table2. I want this to remain the same.

I've accomplished this before easily using an

```
UPDATE
```

with a

```
CASE WHEN
```

but I cannot remember exactly what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `INNER JOIN` not a subquery. This will implicitly filter to only rows where the related row is found:

```sql
UPDATE T1
SET [Value] = T2.Value
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b36a2f9b0c50c5a984baf070bcafb31)

Answer (score 3):

You can also update table1 as :-

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Value=(
SELECT Value
FROM Table2
WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id
);
```

Comment: Larnu's syntax might be dbms specific, at least it didn't seem to work correctly with postgres 14. this syntax did work... however, i'm not sure the parens are needed. they didn't seem to be for my test.